# Get section of input passed to the sanitize_callback

Tags: plugin-development

How can I find out what section each input is in when viewing the `$input` array passed to the sanitize_callback function defined in [`register_setting()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting)?

I suppose one option is to include the section as part of the field name and can then extract it. E.g. `name="section^field"` and then in the sanitize_callback:

```
foreach($input as $name => $val) {
    $parts = explode('^', $name);
    $section = $parts[0];
    $field = $parts[1];
    // do more stuff here
}
```

But this feels a little hacky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if you look at the source the only thing that happens there is:

```
add_filter( "sanitize_option_{$option_name}", $sanitize_callback );
```

There is no opportunity to pass along or retrieve any extra information.

On a larger scale I would say if you need section-specific sanitize then use section-specific callbacks. Even if considerable parts are shared with class based code it should be easy enough to neatly organize.